# How to remove the summary at the beginning of the "top" command in Linux?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, top

I used `top -b -n 2 | awk '{if ($9 != 0.0) print $0,sed -n '8,20p'}'>>text.txt`
 , then the output is :

```
top - 16:24:42 up  3:49,  3 users,  load average: 0.23, 0.29, 0.31
Threads: 503 total,   2 running, 501 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  9.7 us,  1.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 88.5 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3938668 total,  2148708 used,  1789960 free,   133524 buffers
KiB Swap:  3903484 total,        0 used,  3903484 free.   822904 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1054 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.5  0.1   0:00.00 rsyslogd
 1086 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.4  0.1   0:00.03 in:imuxsock
 1087 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.00 in:imklog
 1090 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.05 rs:main Q:Reg
 2452 fpiat     20   0   25292   7520   3580 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.69 bash         
 2495 fpiat     20   0   25088   6988   3256 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.05 bash
top - 16:24:42 up  3:49,  3 users,  load average: 0.23, 0.29, 0.31
Threads: 503 total,   2 running, 501 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  9.7 us,  1.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 88.5 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3938668 total,  2148708 used,  1789960 free,   133524 buffers
KiB Swap:  3903484 total,        0 used,  3903484 free.   822904 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1054 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.5  0.1   0:00.00 rsyslogd
 1086 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.4  0.1   0:00.03 in:imuxsock
 1087 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.00 in:imklog
 1090 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.05 rs:main Q:Reg
 2452 fpiat     20   0   25292   7520   3580 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.69 bash         
 2495 fpiat     20   0   25088   6988   3256 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.05 bash
```

I wish to get the output like below (which means the header is not printed):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1054 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.5  0.1   0:00.00 rsyslogd
 1086 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.4  0.1   0:00.03 in:imuxsock
 1087 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.00 in:imklog
 1090 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.05 rs:main Q:Reg
 2452 fpiat     20   0   25292   7520   3580 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.69 bash         
 2495 fpiat     20   0   25088   6988   3256 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.05 bash
 1054 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.5  0.1   0:00.00 rsyslogd
 1086 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.4  0.1   0:00.03 in:imuxsock
 1087 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.00 in:imklog
 1090 root      20   0  258664   3524   2692 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.05 rs:main Q:Reg
 2452 fpiat     20   0   25292   7520   3580 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.69 bash         
 2495 fpiat     20   0   25088   6988   3256 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.05 bash
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

command:`top -b -n1| sed -n '/PID/,$p'`

output

```
ux_example ~]# top -b -n1| sed -n '/PID/,$p'
   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
     7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  1.7  0.0   0:01.04 migration/1
     1 root      20   0 19356 1564 1252 S  0.0  0.1   0:07.96 init
     2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.07 kthreadd
     3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.46 migration/0
     4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.84 ksoftirqd/0
     5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
     6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:58.23 watchdog/0
     8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
     9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.87 ksoftirqd/1
    10 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   2:10.65 watchdog/1
    11 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.42 migration/2
    12 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2
    13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.27 ksoftirqd/2
    14 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:55.75 watchdog/2
    15 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.03 migration/3
    16 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/3
    17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.95 ksoftirqd/3
    18 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:58.07 watchdog/3
    19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:14.40 events/0
    20 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   3:52.96 events/1
    21 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:16.77 events/2
    22 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:34.48 events/3
    23 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cgroup
    24 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 khelper
    25 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
    26 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 async/mgr
    27 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 pm
    28 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:07.44 sync_supers
    29 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.43 bdi-default
    30 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd/0
    31 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd/1
    32 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd/2
    33 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd/3
    34 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.02 kblockd/0
    35 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.02 kblockd/1
    36 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:07.83 kblockd/2
    37 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:22.51 kblockd/3
38 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:
```

Answer (score 1):

The `top` command is intended for interactive use. To get the output you want in a programmatic way, you might consider using `ps` instead, which can give most of the same information but it is more script-friendly.

Example:

```
$ ps -eo pid,uid,pri,nice,vsz,rss,s,%cpu,%mem,time,comm | head
  PID   UID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS S %CPU %MEM     TIME COMMAND
    1     0  19   0 186380  9608 S  0.0  0.0 00:01:15 systemd
    2     0  19   0      0     0 S  0.0  0.0 00:00:00 kthreadd
    3     0  39 -20      0     0 I  0.0  0.0 00:00:00 rcu_gp
    4     0  39 -20      0     0 I  0.0  0.0 00:00:00 rcu_par_gp
    6     0  39 -20      0     0 I  0.0  0.0 00:00:00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd
    8     0  39 -20      0     0 I  0.0  0.0 00:00:00 mm_percpu_wq
    9     0  19   0      0     0 S  0.0  0.0 00:00:19 ksoftirqd/0
   10     0  41   -      0     0 I  0.0  0.0 00:02:20 rcu_preempt
   11     0  41   -      0     0 S  0.0  0.0 00:00:24 rcuc/0
```

Notice how the only field missing is `SHR`. (I couldn't find out how to get `ps` to print it.)

Comment: On the contrary, the manual for GNU `top` explicitly says that the `-b` option is for sending output "to other programs".

Comment: @JdeBP Okay, how well is that working for OP?

Comment: @JdeBP I mean, if you think you have a better Answer ... where is it?

Comment: You are constructing a false dilemma, when you could instead be fixing your answer.  Your answer begins with an outright denial of what the manual for the command specifically says about the way that the questioner is using it.  This is not an auspicious beginning to an answer.

Comment: @JdeBP If you want to help me improve my answer, simply nitpicking over the manual is not the way to go. From what is posted in the question, it would appear that the manual contradicts observables. In the question we see that despite the use of `-b`, `top` does _not_ behave in a way that works well with other programs. I will defer to what can be observed. Again, you may feel encouraged to post an alternative Answer if your familiarity with `top`'s manual furnishes you with some insight into how to do what is required without switching from `top` to `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

The various components of the Summary Area can be enabled or disabled as follows:

```
       Summary-Area-defaults
          'l' - Load Avg/Uptime  On  (thus program name)
          't' - Task/Cpu states  On  (1+1 lines, see '1')
          'm' - Mem/Swap usage   On  (2 lines worth)
          '1' - Single Cpu       On  (thus 1 line if smp)
```

To disable all of them, start `top` then press each of the <kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd> keys until those lines disappear (some of them cycle through a few modes, rather than being simple on-off toggles).  Then save your changes to `.toprc` with <kbd>W</kbd>.

After that, `top -b -n 1` will show only a blank line, the column header line, and the individual lines for each process.

The configuration file is, for the most part, human-readable, so you could edit it directly, but it doesn't appear to be designed for that.  (Notably, the `fieldscur` field contains characters from outside the usual ASCII range.)  The parts you want to disable are all represented by bits in the `winflags` entry, but the exact values (as well as the location of the config file) may vary between different versions.